# JSP to immediately redirect to Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect

I need to display information retrieved from a `SQL` Database on my welcome page (the 1st page shown to the user).

What is the correct way of going about doing this?

Should I have some sort of redirect on the `JSP` page to a `servlet` and then the `servlet` will redirect to another `jsp` page for the information to be displayed? If so, how would I perform the redirect on the `jsp` page?

Or is there a better alternative?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either ways .

**First Template** :

I hope you implement a proper MVC architecture. If you are showing the welcome page after **user's login** , then follow these steps,

1.After `submitting` from **login.jsp** , handle the request in `servlet`

2.Get the values from the `database` and add it to the `request` or `session` attribute

1. forward the page response to the **welcome.jsp**

4.Populate the results in the page

**Second Template:**

you can use the `jstl` tags to populate the result from the database on page load . see [JSTL SQL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

For example,

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
     user="root"  password="pass123"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from TableName;
</sql:query>
```

A [very good example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_query_tag.htm) for beginners here

Hope this helps !!